# Comparing versions with maven artifact api ComparableVersion

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to compare two maven versions and see which one is the newest version.

I found `ComparableVersion`.

I tried this code as a start:

```
ComparableVersion cv1 = new ComparableVersion("0.0.1-SNAPSHOT");
ComparableVersion cv2 = new ComparableVersion("1.0.0-SNAPSHOT");
System.out.println(cv1.compareTo(cv2));
```

This returns a value of -1. I could not, find any guides on what this means or anything. I found the source for `ComparableVersion` but there was no documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javadoc of [CompareVersion.compareTo()](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html#compareTo(org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.ComparableVersion)), you will see it is specified by [Comparable.compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true), which has a javdoc of:

> Returns:
>
> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.